# Normal Magic Square (By Loop)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

Does anyone know how to implement a function to determine if a matrix is a magic square? For example:

```
>>> is_magic_square([[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]])
True
```

Here is my approach for sum of rows:

```
def row_sum(rows):
  return (list (map (lambda x: sum(x), rows)))
```

I am wondering how to get the sum of two diagonals.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Transpose the matrix and check for sums. Check for sums normally. Then check the two diagonals.

Comment: how to transpose the list of list in python? @MalikBrahimi

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
rows = all(sum(row) == sum(matrix[0]) for row in matrix)
cols = all(sum(col) == sum(map(list, zip(*matrix))[0]) for col in matrix)

diag1 = sum(matrix[i][i] for i in range(3)) == sum(matrix[0])
diag1 = sum(matrix[2-i][i] for i in range(3)) == sum(matrix[0])

print rows and cols and diag1 and diag2 # magic or not
```